# How can I make an object with an interface like a random number generator, but that actually generates a specified sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'd like to construct an object that works like a random number generator, but generates numbers in a specified sequence.

```
# a random number generator
rng = lambda : np.random.randint(2,20)//2

# a non-random number generator
def nrng():
    numbers = np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        yield numbers[i]

for j in range(10):
    print('random number', rng())
    print('non-random number', nrng())
```

The issue with the code above that I cannot call `nrng` in the last line because it is a generator. I know that the most straightforward way to rewrite the code above is to simply loop over the non-random numbers instead of defining the generator. I would prefer getting the example above to work because I am working with a large chunk of code that include a function that accepts a random number generator as an argument, and I would like to add the functionality to pass non-random number sequences without rewriting the entire code.

EDIT: I see some confusion in the comments. I am aware that python's random number generators generate pseudo-random numbers. This post is about replacing a pseudo-random-number generator by a number generator that generates numbers from a **non-random, user-specified** sequence (e.g., a generator that generates the number sequence `1,1,2,2,1,0,1` if I want it to).

Comment: Do you want to be able to continuously sample from your non-random number pool? Or do you want it to exhaust? If you have an actual sequence, and not just the toy example above, can you write a recurrence relation for it?

Comment: As an aside, you *could* use seeding to still take advantage of RNG while also making it reproducible. I'm assuming you want this functionality for some sort of debugging?

Comment: This is how all number generators work. Show me an algorithm to generate something truly random :)

Comment: Such a generator is sometimes called a "deterministic" generator.  They often get used in unit testing to replace randomness to help test corner cases that are extremely rare with proper psudorandom numbers, but can be made to occur quickly with the right sequence.

Comment: I can't believe no one has mentioned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: @whatsisname Seems rather easy to believe, as that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm genuinely confused. Aren't all pseudo random number generators entirely deterministic (hence the "pseudo")? You need to sample true entropy for serious applications like encryption.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Python's for example isn't. Not entirely. It usually seeds non-deterministically. Only after that it's deterministic. And I could imagine prngs that mix deterministic and non-deterministic, e.g., "reseed" non-deterministically every now and then (flipping a single bit in its state might suffice, so could be efficient).

Comment: @KellyBundy The PRNG of the simulation is pretty good. (That is, it passes the relevant tests.)

Comment: @KellyBundy Re "flip a bit now and then": If you do that deterministically, it's still deterministic. If not, you introduced "true entropy" (true inside the simulation) ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You introduce *some*. It would still be partially deterministic, and as long as that's the case, I think it's still only pseudorandom.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit:

The cleanest way to do this would be to use a lambda to wrap your call to `next(nrng)` as per great comment from @GACy20:

```
def nrng_gen():
    yield from range(10)

nrng = nrng_gen()

nrng_func = lambda: next(nrng)

for i in range(10):
    print(nrng_func())
```

Original answer:

If you want your object to keep state and look like a function, create a custom class with `__call__` method.

eg.

```
class NRNG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = range(10)
        self.state = -1
    def __call__(self):
        self.state += 1
        return self.numbers[self.state]
        
nrng = NRNG()


for i in range(10):
    print(nrng())
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this unless absolutely necessary, as it obscures the fact that your nrng keeps a state (although technically, most rngs keep their state internally).

It's best to just use a regular generator with `yield` by calling next on it or to write a custom iterator (also class-based). Those will work with things like for loops and other python tools for iteration (like the excellent itertools package).

Answer (score 20):

You can call `next()` with a generator or iterator as an argument to withdraw exactly one element from it. Saving the generator to a variable beforehand allows you to do this multiple times.

```
# make it a generator
def _rng():
    while True:
        yield np.random.randint(2,20)//2

# a non-random number generator
def _nrng():
    numbers = np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        yield numbers[i]

rng = _rng()
nrng = _nrng()
for j in range(10):
    print('random number', next(rng))
    print('non-random number', next(nrng))
```

Comment: This is an excellent (and upvoted) point. But you could achieve the same effect with less overhead with `def _nrng(): return iter(np.arange(1, 10.5, 0.5))` (or even `_nrng = lambda:np.arange(1, 10.5, 0.5)`).

Comment: I think OP wants to receive the "next number" by just doing `nrng()`, since downstream code which presumably accepts `nrng` will call it that way.

Comment: I think OP should consider explicitly using `next()` though, as it is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Instead of passing `nrng` they can use `lambda: next(nrng)` as argument...

Comment: @GACy20 That's a much better answer to this question than this one. Green Cloak Guy's answer is true generally, but does not answer the actual question asked.

Answer (score 7):

`np.random.randint` can remember the last number it generated because it's a function of the `np.random.RandomState` class. Numpy simply aliases the class method so that it's accessible directly from the `np.random` module instead of having you access it through the class.

Knowing this, you can write your own class to work like so:

```
class NotRandom:

    numbers = np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)
    last_index = -1

    @classmethod
    def nrng(cls):
        cls.last_index += 1
        if cls.last_index < len(cls.numbers):
            return cls.numbers[cls.last_index]
        # else:
        return None

# Create an alias to the classmethod
nrng = NotRandom.nrng      # Note this is OUTSIDE the class
```

Then, you can do:

```
print(nrng())    # 1.0
print(nrng())    # 1.5
print(nrng())    # 2.0
```

---

If you want to be able to have multiple concurrent instances of `nrng`, you could make `nrng()` an *instance method* instead of a class method:

```
class NotRandom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)
        self.last_index = -1

    def nrng(self):
        self.last_index += 1
        if self.last_index < len(self.numbers):
            return self.numbers[self.last_index]
        # else:
        return None

# Create an object. Then create an alias to its method
nrng = NotRandom().nrng
```

Then, you can use `nrng()` to refer to the method that's bound to the `NotRandom` instance you created. If you want another instance, you can have that too:

```
another_notrandom = NotRandom()
nrng2 = another_notrandom.rng

print(nrng())    # 1.0
print(nrng())    # 1.5

print(nrng2())   # 1.0

print(nrng())    # 2.0

print(nrng2())   # 1.5
```

Comment: It's really weird that you chose to use a class method.

Comment: Why? @user253751

Comment: well... what is the point of having a class without instances?

Comment: @user253751 to keep track of state?

Comment: you don't need a class for what is effectively a global variable

Comment: @user253751 [Global variables are a not such a great idea.](//stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/843953) The class nicely encapsulates all the information relevant to its own calculations within itself. If you want multiple instances of the generator, don't make it a class method like the second half of my answer shows. Static functions and static classes are a thing in lots of other languages. This isn't some python-specific shenanigans (you should know, you have a gold badge in java and c++)

Answer (score 5):

> function that accepts a random number generator as an argument

Call it like this then:

```
that_function(nrng().__next__)
```

Or with `functools.partial`:

```
that_function(partial(next, nrng()))
```

Or without your generator, if that `arange` is all you want:

```
that_function(iter(np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)).__next__)
```

Demo code (`rng` and `nrng` are yours, I added `that_function` and the test calls):

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

# a random number generator
rng = lambda : np.random.randint(2,20)//2

# a non-random number generator
def nrng():
    numbers = np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        yield numbers[i]

def that_function(rng):
    print(*(rng() for j in range(10)))

that_function(rng)
that_function(nrng().__next__)
that_function(iter(np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)).__next__)
that_function(partial(next, nrng()))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHRasQgEEXf/YqBvmhJs0lKXxb6JaXIbGOylmSUiQubr88atRS2XUEE595zZ9Sv4ezoddvs7B0HoMvsV8AFyIuB3QzDhb6Cc9MCReGRg8VJiCdAYKQ@iqLrZBhGQ4YxOBZMI7zDhPOpRzhGWJ2V6bAUZFd1jTocuowhRy@PUL0ZgCJPqqOAuLJgifhIxegajWyrtqnfqrhV0gyOwYIlyOXJkCw2VSj7Wq2Z@h/eh/0UKSucMeg0tXUkY3BxeN77fpaplZTw/ZvQNkopIf56767yILXWZK5B6/uyDYblv2M99pT/kHu1Ki@l1LbdAA)):

```
4 6 1 3 8 7 3 6 2 1
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5
```

Comment: This is the best answer, if OP really wants to avoid refactoring their code.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to making a generator callable is to make a bound method for `__next__`:

```
>>> def f():
        yield 10
        yield 20
        yield 30
    
>>> g = f().__next__
>>> g()
10
>>> g()
20
>>> g()
30
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree, next() seems the way to go. Honestly I would have simply done something like this:

```
# Get the first n numbers (10 in this case)

for i,j in enumerate(nrng()):  
    if i > 9:
        break
    print('random number', rng())
    print('non-random number', j)
    
# Or this if you want to get all numbers in nrng()

for j in nrng():
    print('random number', rng())
    print('non-random number', j)
```